# CSS Background Image with Horizontal Gradient

Tags: background-image, gradient, css

I have an issue to use an image with gradient as the background image for the main menu bar.

This the image for the background:
[image]

As you may know, the image has 2 gradient, first, the very far left and secondly 3/4 to the right. What I want to achieve is like this:

[image]

Does anyone know the best practice to do this? I know the only problem with this is the width of the browser, where I need to make sure the very far left will start with very light grey. The very far right, will be the dark grey.

Another problem that I have is the center gradient for the main page:

[image]

This is a little bit easier and can be done by CSS gradient. However, I have been trying to set the gradient start from the center, behind the yellow div.

If anyone knows how the best way to achieve this, that would be great.

Thank you for you help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If just use the image as an background image?

```
<div style="width: 896px; height: 20px;background-image: url(bg.png);"><div style="padding-left: 250px;">test</div></div>
```

Comment: Sorry for the delay responding your reply, I will try your recommendation. Will update the result. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this purely in css, you could make two containers with a gradient each, that way they could change width and it would still look the same.

For example

HTML:

```
<div id="container">
   <div id="gradient1"></div>
   <div id="gradient2"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.container { ..... }
.gradient1 {width:60%; float:left; GRADIENT}
.gradient2 {width:40%; float:left; GRADIENT}
```